# Fill form using beautifulsoup without knowing id or name

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to fill form (composed of email, credit card, name, phone ecc.) without knowing html info. Maybe I could know the order of field

Answer (score 1):

Beautiful soup is for pulling information from HTML, not for inputting information. You'll want to use selenium to input information into a webform. In selenium, you can find an element by link text or partial link text if you do not know the html info. However, you can easily find HTML info for any webpage by left clicking and selecting 'view page source' so I am not sure when would be a circumstance you wouldn't have that information..

More on selenium here:
https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html